# Parent node and Child node not showing up in asp.menu (with web.sitemap)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working in a project that uses an asp.menu that consumes a web.sitemap file. I've added a submenu like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="formPaginaPrincipal.aspx" title="Página Inicial"  description="Pagina inicial do site">
    <siteMapNode url="listaModalidades.aspx" title="Modalidades"  description="Modalidades de licitações" />
    <siteMapNode url="" title="Relatórios" description="Relatórios do sistema">
      <siteMapNode url="list.aspx" title="testing"></siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode url="listaTiposLicitacao.aspx" title="Tipos de Licitação"  description="Tipos de licitações" />
    <siteMapNode url="listaOrgaos.aspx" title="Órgãos"  description="Órgãos do governo de Pernambuco" />
    <siteMapNode url="listaComissoes.aspx" title="Comissões"  description="Comissões de licitações" />
    <siteMapNode url="listaLicitacoes.aspx" title="Licitações"  description="Licitações" />
    <siteMapNode url="ArquivarLicitacoes.aspx" title="Arquivar Licitações"  description="Arquivamento de Licitações" />
    <siteMapNode url="listaEmpresas.aspx" title="Fornecedores"  description="Fornecedores" />
    <siteMapNode url="listaUsuarios.aspx" title="Usuários"  description="Usuários de Órgãos do governo de Pernambuco" />
    <siteMapNode url="formPaginaPrincipal.aspx?acao=sair" title="Sair"  description="Encerrar Sessão" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

If i switch to display mode in the aspx file, i can see the parent node "Relatorios"...but when i run the project, it doesn't show up at all. I've debugged the project and it's like the itemdatabound event for this node ("Relatorios") doesn't fire up at all. If i remove its child node ("testing"), it will work normally. Why is this happening?

My aspmenu and asp.sitemapdatasource in my masterpage:

```
<asp:Menu ID="mnuPrincipal" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" 
                    StaticDisplayLevels="2" Width="208px" 
                onmenuitemclick="mnuPrincipal_MenuItemClick" 
                OnMenuItemDataBound="mnuPrincipal_temDataBound" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" 
                StaticSubMenuIndent="40px" >
                <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="menu" />
                <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="selecionado" />
                <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="sub-menu" />
                <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="menu" />
                <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="selecionado" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="sub-menu" />
                </asp:Menu>

<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" StartFromCurrentNode="false" />
```

Comment: As it has no URL it probably will not get rendered - try putting a # for the URL and see if it shows up.

Comment: thanks man! it worked! But now there's one thing goin on: it shows a white box of some sort in IE8 (i've applied the css fix but it didn't work) and when i run it on chrome, the parent node shows up but not the child node...

Comment: No worries. Not sure about the IE8 issue - sounds like a CSS issue. You might want to start a new question and post the relevant CSS.

Comment: In terms of Chrome - compare the generated source against IE8. Old versions of the framework treated Chrome as a downlevel browser and rendered completly different markup! See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652093/i-fixed-the-safari-aspmenu-issue-using-addedcontrol-method-why-does-this-work

Answer (score 0):

you can declare your sitemap in your configuration

```
siteMap enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add siteMapFile="Web.sitemap" name="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" securityTrimmingEnabled="true"/>
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: It's already declared in the web.config file. As i said, the weird thing is: if i check an aspx file in design mode, i can see the asp.menu (since it is in the masterpage) and i can see the parent node i've added. But when i run the project, it simply doesn't appear in the menu at all. Its menuitemdatabound event does not fire  as well...